# fglrx removed in favor of Gallium 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, fglrx, gpu-driver, gallium

I downgraded my system through fresh reinstall to ubuntu 14.04. I installed fglrx 'successfully' but when I tried to play a game the FPS was pathetic compared to what it used to be. I found recently that the OpenGL version was 1.4 and I linked this to it. Ubuntu flashed me a graphics stack security update which I accepted and upon reboot I'm back on Gallium 0.4. Does anyone know what is going wrong here to make fglrx fail so much?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMD's fglrx install problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/809038/amds-fglrx-install-problems)

Comment: @CelticWarrior this issue is different - it used to work fine when i used to have 14.04 and now it doesnt

Comment: Then it's no different. There is explained what happened with 14.04.**5** with the xenial kernel and HWE, the one you mentioned by "graphics stack security update" (but it's not just about graphics). In a nutshell, `fglrx` is not compatible with the new kernel/HWE and the OS reverted to the open source `radeon` and that's all there is for your hardware currently. The new fglrx replacement, the `amdgpu-pro` driver only supports newer graphics.

Comment: And you already knew that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/812889/how-do-i-install-amd-graphics-drivers-for-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @CelticWarrior ah crap, thanks. it still seems to work okay on my laptop funnily, maybe because i installed an old kernel to do so